# Silverstripe Gatsby endpoint is returning error and null data

Tags: gatsby, silverstripe-4

I am struggling to run the Gatsby Module on my Silverstripe project.

Here is my composer file:

```
{
"name": "silverstripe/installer",
"type": "silverstripe-recipe",
"description": "The SilverStripe Framework Installer",
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.3",
    "silverstripe/recipe-plugin": "^1.3",
    "silverstripe/recipe-cms": "4.5.0@stable",
    "silverstripe-themes/simple": "^3.2.0",
    "silverstripe/spamprotection": "^3.0.1",
    "silverstripe/silverstripe-gatsby": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.7"
},
"extra": {
    "resources-dir": "_resources",
    "project-files-installed": [
        "app/.htaccess",
        "app/_config.php",
        "app/_config/mysite.yml",
        "app/src/Page.php",
        "app/src/PageController.php"
    ],
    "public-files-installed": [
        ".htaccess",
        "index.php",
        "web.config"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "process-timeout": 600
},
"prefer-stable": true,
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

}

I added it to my composer according to the plugin page.

```
composer require silverstripe/silverstripe-gatsby
```

When I try to check the endpoint which is:

```
http://example.com/__gatsby/graphql
```

I am getting this:

```
{"data":null,"errors":[{"message":"Syntax Error: Unexpected <EOF>","locations":[{"line":1,"column":1}]}]}
```

I tried to check the logs but no clue of whats going on. No errors were found in there.

Is there a way to enable the debug or something that gives me some hints on how to solve this?

Comment: PS: The website is working normally and no errors are showing in the logs.

Comment: I had to add this to the config to get gatsby working:
```
SilverStripe\Gatsby\GraphQL\Types\SyncResultTypeCreator:
  filter_can_view: false
```
You might also install `silverstripe/graphql-devtools` for a graphiql interface for Silverstripe